# Math: Average out lines in polar coordinate system (c++ opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, mathematical-optimization

I am using OpenCV for some line detection with [HoughLines](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html). Then I look for there intersections.

This is the end result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGd8k.png

(green dots being the intersections and red lines being the raw lines after houghlines operation)

As you can see there are a lot of lines detected and to compute intersections each and every line is compiled with each other thus extremely increasing the processing time.

I am looking to optimize the number of lines by averaging out similar lines after the initial HoughLines operation.

The problem is that HoughLines outputs the data in polar coordinate system and so far I was not able to find any similar code or a mathematical equation to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: added R, Phi sorted according to the line it belongs to.

```
R Phi    -11.000   ,    3.124
R Phi     15.000   ,    0.000
R Phi     13.000   ,    0.000
R Phi     22.000   ,    0.000
R Phi    -18.000   ,    3.124
R Phi     -9.000   ,    3.107
R Phi    -10.000   ,    3.089
R Phi     -7.000   ,    3.089
R Phi     19.000   ,    0.017
R Phi     -6.000   ,    3.107
R Phi     -4.000   ,    3.072
R Phi    -14.000   ,    3.107
R Phi     27.000   ,    0.017

R Phi    172.000   ,    1.553
R Phi    165.000   ,    1.553
R Phi    173.000   ,    1.536
R Phi    170.000   ,    1.571
R Phi    166.000   ,    1.536

R Phi   -163.000   ,    3.107
R Phi    169.000   ,    0.017
R Phi    172.000   ,    0.035
R Phi   -165.000   ,    3.124
R Phi   -159.000   ,    3.124
R Phi    165.000   ,    0.000
R Phi    167.000   ,    0.000
R Phi    167.000   ,    0.035
R Phi   -155.000   ,    3.107

R Phi    313.000   ,    1.571
R Phi    319.000   ,    1.536
R Phi    312.000   ,    1.588
R Phi    315.000   ,    1.553
R Phi    317.000   ,    1.553

R Phi     24.000   ,    1.536
R Phi     26.000   ,    1.518
R Phi     22.000   ,    1.553
```

An average or delta would work fine I guess but I need to learn as to why negative values have different theta. In practical view the difference appears to be Pi so for every negative value I could go with abs(r) and Pi-Phi.

However I need to know if this is a 100 % full proof solution.

EDIT2: After testing I am sure that I was not exactly right here... The lines plainly switched place...

Comment: Have you tried to change the _threshold_ parameter of the HoughLines function? It could already filter some of the lines...

Comment: Lowering the threshold any lower causes it to not detect an edge at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather from the documentation the HoughLines function returns a parametrization of the lines in polar coordinates. So the (*r*, *phi*) tuple describes the shortest distance of the line to the origin and the angle between the line from the origin to the point of shortest distance and the *x* axis. The sketch from the function documentation illustrates the situation (there is a right angle between the blue and red line):

[image: Illustration of the parametrization]

Now, if two lines are similar, they may be tilted a bit against each other and their distance of closest approach to the origin will vary slightly. So, you can just coalesce detected lines that differ by less than a *DeltaR* and a *DeltaPhi* (simultaneously), e.g. by taking the means of the parameters. You can also perform a weighted average if you have some kind of measure of how trustworthy the detected lines are. How big the tolerances should be depends very much on your coordinate system and your application. Of course, as albemala said, raising the threshold of the algorithm to produce less false lines in the first place will help with getting more precise results.

**Edit:** The above assumes that there are no ambiguities in the parameters. As this is not the case here, you have to fold *r* to [0,∞) and *phi* to [0,2π). If *r* is negative flip its sign and add π to *phi*, then add a multiple of 2π to *phi* so that the result is in the range 0 <= *phi* < 2π. You will always have a branch cut somewhere, where *phi* jumps by 2π. This complicates the comparison of angles and their average:
You have to compare angles "modulo 2π", i.e. for two angles *phi1*, *phi2* take the smaller of `abs(phi1-phi2)` and `abs(abs(phi1-phi2)-2π)` as their difference.

After you identified the lines that should be coalesced you have to bring their *phi* values numerically close together for the average, e.g. by adding 2π to the values smaller than π. You can then fold the averaged value back into the range [0,2π).

**Edit 2:** Values of *phi* less than π combined with a negative *r* can only caused by lines going through sectors 2 (x<0, y>0), 3 (x<0, y<0) and 4 (x>0, y<0) of the coordinate system. These lines will never be visible in sector 1 (x>0, y>0). Therefore, if you only consider lines through *this* sector *phi* - π will be in the range [0,2π) an you can save the folding step. You still have to cope with the branch cut at *phi* = 0 when averaging and measuring angle differences, though.

Comment: Edited the original post with r phi data. I already tried the mean solution but due to the negative values it failed. Now when looking at the values I noticed that the difference in between negative R's Phi and positive R's Phi is Pi. I guess that some lines are recorded as turned by 180 degs...

Comment: Only the results of HoughLines are in the range of [0,2π). After the transformation I do not really need this limitation anymore. So since the results are in the range of [0,2π) and an image matrix coordinates are limited to the 1st quarter (x>0; y>0) couldn't I just subtract? Phi - Pi? From a practical standpoint I did not see any ambiguities. The formula I used is abs(r) and Phi-Pi. However all my lines are close to being parallel to X or Y axes. I wonder what will happen once I start flipping them...

Comment: In general you will have phi values over the full range, e.g. a 45° line intercepting the y-axis at a positive value results in phi = 125°. If you only have lines going through the first quadrant you will never have negative r values combined with phi values less than π so your method will never produce negative phi values.

Comment: One last question: How can I find the angle between 2 intersecting lines defined in this context?